# How to run sequential Tasks in an ExecutorService

Tags: java

I would like to execute **different** tasks for each player in an event executor, but make sure that the tasks submitted for each player are in order. Here is a picture to hopefully explain in better.

[image: Visual representation of what I am trying to accomplish]

Extra Information:

1. I know which player will be effected for each task
2. I receive the tasks for each player in a pseudo-random order. (I will not know the order of task input before hand)
3. I need each player to basically have their own "thread" so that their tasks execute in order of insertion.

What I have tried:

Currently I am using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` inside of each player object to mimic this functionality, but I don't think this will scale well with a lot of players. Hence why I am asking here to find a better method.

Comment: You can build this with akka actors.

Comment: How many players do you expect to have? Using a `singleThreadExecutor` is an unnecessary step for a thread-per-client approach, but that's exactly what you're aiming for. You can worry about scaling when it becomes a problem.

Comment: When I publish the code, it is sent to multiple servers that can have between 0 to about 600 players.

Comment: Why do you "need each player to have their own thread"? It just needs to be guaranteed that events arriving for a given player don't get executed out of order, no, so the `singleThreadExecutor` does what that, no? And why don't you just create a `singleThreadExecutor` for each player, which would scale it up.

Comment: @Heirteir 600 players/threads is not an issue. Your player threads just each need a queue to `take()` on and someone to distribute the tasks to the right queues.

Comment: When I said "thread" I didn't mean a literal thread, I just couldn't think of a better word for it, I am pretty new concurrency. In response to @ShankarShastri I don't have access to that library in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three main ways of achieving this.

### Thread per player

This is a bit like what you are doing. Create a thread per player, dispatch work units to it; this is serial by nature.

It *may* not scale well to a few hundreds / thousands of players (a few hundred active threads usually do not scare mordern hardware - although it may not be really efficient).

But the readability and ligthness of the code will probably be unmatched by other solutions.

### Shared threads with consistent routing

If a thread per player is not possible, then we will have to share threads, and a thread will deal with several players.

The key will be to have a given thread handle *every* task for a given player, so as to achieve serial execution.

Three ways of building this come to mind...

#### Create groups of players

If your players have something to allow for grouping (e.g. a Team, or even just a creation date)... then regroup your players by group, and implement a "Thread per group" pattern.

The only key issue is to have groups of roughly the same size, so as to share the load evenly.

Another issue, that you will have in almost every solution, will be to shutdown the thread for the group (how do you know when everything you wanted to process is finished ?).

#### Shared threads and ExecutorService

This is the "do it yourself way". The gist of it is

1. create a `fixedThreadPool`, say with 4 threads.
2. Create a 4 `BlockingQueue` that will hold every work units
3. Create 4 `PlayerWorker` instances and send them to the thread pool to being execution, one for each of the above `BlockingQueue`. The implementation of these workers is to pull data from *one* of the queues and execute it.
4. Dispatch your player work units by sending them to the queue. The key here is to **always reuse the same queue for the same player** (e.g. if your player has an identifier property, say a long, then dispatch all work units to the `Math.abs(id % 4)`th queue
5. Shut down the `PlayerWorker` and thread pool when everything is done

This is a lot of work, so...

#### Using a framework

Some people have already done it for you. The actor pattern is a very good fit for this problem. You should probably check out Akka and what is called `ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic`, which is a pretty much one to one mapping, conceptually at least, to what I just described.

### The reactive way

If we step back a bit, we do not actually care about *threads*. We care about *serial execution*.

So we just need a way to perform some work after some other work is done. It should be just a call back !

And we have `CompletableFuture` for that (not to mention frameworks).

So why not create one `CompletableFuture` per player, and each time a new work unit is to be done for this player, use `CompletableFuture.thenApply` or `thenApplyAsync`.

By dispatching the executions to an appropriately sized execution pool, and letting the framework do the job, the tasks will be serially executed one after the other.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful response! Your fixedThreadPool solution looks perfect for what I am trying to accomplish!

Comment: @Heirteir and that's what I was describing in my comment. Except I was suggesting you do it with a thread and queue per player, since you're new and when you're new you should concentrate on getting it to be correct instead of guessing that "this might be slow if I have a million players".

Comment: No problem. I've been there a few times, and I understand grasping actor patterns and adding libraries to a code base is not easy, so "rolling your own" has some appeal. But if that's your case, I'd think twice... CompletableFutures require no framework, are pretty easy and will, I guess, prove easier to work with and produce less code / thread pool sizing and tuning issues, or end-of-work detection / shutdown than a manual Producer/Consumer approach like the thread pool.

Comment: @GPI I will read up on CompletableFutures before I try the other implementation thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: @GPI Update: Just wanted to say thank you. The CompletableFuture was the perfect thing to use in this instance, and it is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a `singleEventExecutorService` for each player.

```
class PlayerEventHandler {
    private Map<Player, ExecutorService> executors = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void handleEvent(PlayerEvent e) {
        ExecutorService executor = executors.computeIfAbsent(e.getPlayer(), Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        executor.submit(e.execute());
    }
}
```

Although this would probably behave much worse for 600 players than a single thread executor. However, you can probably group the players in some way so that a reasonable amount of players share an executor.

```
class PlayerEventHandler {
    private Map<PlayerGroup, ExecutorService> executors = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void handleEvent(PlayerEvent e) {
        PlayerGroup group = determineGroup(e.getPlayer());
        ExecutorService executor = executors.computeIfAbsent(group, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        executor.submit(e.execute());
    }
}
```

This will probably become a problem if the players change dynamically during runtime, because then you can end up with a single thread handling a lot of players, while another group has become empty over time.

It really depends on your actual case.